# Multiple static_assert's that depend on the same value

Tags: c++, c++14

I am filtering a tuple at compile time, I want to output a custom error message if the tuple is empty or if the tuple contains more than one element.

`static_assert` seems a bit too complicated because I need to use boolean logic.

```
static_assert(size != 0 || size >= 1, "Empty");
static_assert(size == 1 || size == 0, "More than 1");
```

I don't suppose that something like this would be possible?

```
static_if(size == 0) compile_err("Empty");
static_if(size > 1) compile_err("More than 1");
```

Do newer version of C++ offer an alternative to static_assert?

Comment: Why do you need more complicated logic with `static_assert`? Reversing your two `static_if` conditions should work the same way. In the first `static_assert` you have, assuming an unsigned type, `size ≠ 0 ⇔ size ≥ 1`, so either one is redundant.

Comment: `static_assert( size != 0, "Must not be empty")` and `static_assert(size <= 1, "Too many")` appear to be what you want.

Comment: @MatsPetersson You are right, I am not sure why I didn't write it like you.  I think I must have been confused that `false` triggers the assert and not `true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`static_assert` allows boolean logic. What it does not allow is calling (non-`constexpr`) functions. So there is no reason you can't use that logic in your code.

```
static_assert(sizeof(Args...) != 0, "Empty");
static_assert(sizeof(Args...) < 2, "More than 1");
```

Comment: It appears that I was just confused, but you need to negate your two expressions before I can accept the answer, because `static_assert` triggers at `false`.